# Manage Unity windows with Ruby

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-unity, window-management

I am using Ubuntu with the Unity desktop and I would like to write a Ruby script that minimizes all of my Chrome windows and opens my LibreOffice Calc window. I'm sure there is an API for this, but whenever I Google "Ruby Unity API", "Ruby Unity Window Management" or "manage Unity from CLI", I get erroneous results. Could someone please point me in the direction of which Gem I should be using or alternatively what shell commands I should be investigating?

Comment: Ha. Good point. I assumed that everything in Ubuntu can be scripted. Maybe I should just be looking into automating keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I should have been Googling is "AutoIt for Linux", where I would have discovered the scripting too called "AutoKey", which includes functions for windows manipulation. I'm going to leave this post up for posterity.

Actually, if you're feeling keen on using the command line, you can actually use `wmctrl`.